# How to set Entity Framework connection programmatically based on POST

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a small internal application where the user has to submit their db credentials to access their own database.  The db structure is all the same so the models should work fine.  I am wondering if this way is the best way to create the database connection programatically based on what the user submits.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitRepair(FormCollection form)
    {
        using(var connection = CreateConnection(CreateConnectionString(form["dbServer"], form["dbDatabase"], form["dbUser"], form["dbPassword"])))
        {
            using(var context = new MyContext(connection, true))
            {
                foreach(var someEntity in context.SomeEntitySet)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(someEntity.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

this is my post that calls the following

```
private DbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    private string CreateConnectionString(string server, string databaseName, string userName, string password)
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = server, // server address
            InitialCatalog = databaseName, // database name
            IntegratedSecurity = false, // server auth(false)/win auth(true)
            MultipleActiveResultSets = false, // activate/deactivate MARS
            PersistSecurityInfo = true, // hide login credentials
            UserID = userName, // user name
            Password = password // password
        };
        return builder.ConnectionString;
    }
```

Comment: Why user should pass props of DB connection ? I think this not good idea

Comment: because its internal and they have to use this on their own database.

Comment: Being an internal program is not a good reason to share connection string specifics between end-user.

Comment: I think your aproximation is correct. Maybe, add some check validating user imput and error control in the controller. Also you can provide a dropdown with an alias to select server/database, so you avoid exposing internal data

Answer (score 1):

As others said it's not a great idea but I'm sure you have reasons. You can create a DbContext by passing a connection string into the constructor, then allow it to manage its own connection objects.

Declare your constructor like this.

```
public DataContext(string connectionstring):base(connectionstring)
```

I assume you're using Database First EF, if you're using Code First you will have problems!

Comment: The question is about how to build at runtime the connectionstring, not how to pass it to the DbContext

Comment: I didn't read it like that, the SqlConnectionStringBuilder does that job just fine. OP asked "if this way is the best way to create the database connection programatically". My suggestion is to allow the DbContext to handle creating the connection.